# Get CameraOutput rendered properly on top

Tags: swift, swiftui, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I have folllowing code:

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CameraView()
        }
...

override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Set up the video preview view.
        previewView.session = session
        previewView.videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = videoGravity
        previewView.videoPreviewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        previewView.frame = view.frame
...
```

How to get my CameraPreview rendered on top of the view. Because there is that topmargin I don't know where it comes from.

It's very strange, if I try `previewView.frame.offset(x: 0, y: -90)`, it looks nearly perfect, but that's not a solution, that's bad coding.

[Here is a Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lyr5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

try using .edgesIgnoringSafeArea

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        CameraView()
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top) // Ignore the top safe area
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Now, it's more centered, yes - but still now at very top.

Comment: Think of the size and shape of your image, how it would look on devices with various viewing dimensions.  Also, though I don’t think it will change, try .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) then there is also .scaledToFill().

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will work

let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()

previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill